# Is $\langle T \rangle$ the smallest subring of a ring $R$ that contains $T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$R$ is a ring. Prove that,

> For nonempty subset $T$ of $R$, the set
>
> $\langle T \rangle = \cap \{S| T\subseteq S$, $S$ is a subring of $R\}$
>
> is the smallest subring of $R$ to contain $T$.

Comment: Please don't use pictures. $(b)$ is just a definition, what exactly is your question on it?

Comment: It is a ring because $1\in S\supset T$, with $S$ subring of $R$ and if $a,b,c\in \langle T\rangle$, then $a,b,c$ is inside all $S\supset T$, with $S$ subring of $R$. Then $a+bc\in S$ for all those $S$. Hence $a+bc\in \langle T\rangle$. On the other hand any subring of $R$ containing $T$ will be in that intersection, and therefore would contain $\langle T\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider $\langle 666 \rangle$, a subring of $\mathbb Z$. Plenty of other ideals contain $666$, including $\langle 2 \rangle$, $\langle 3 \rangle$, $\langle 6 \rangle$, etc. These all properly contain $\langle 666 \rangle$. But no ideal smaller than $\langle 666 \rangle$ can contain $666$. Mwahahahaha!

Comment: mwahaha--- that's a "short one".

Answer (score 1):

well, an intersection of rings is a ring, so the defined set is in fact a ring.
minimality: 
let S be some ring that contains T, by definition S will be in the intersection defining  and therefore  is contained in S, proving minimality